# Optimizing onDraw in Android - which area is being redrawn?

Tags: android, optimization, ondraw

In my android app, I have a custom View implementing onDraw().

I know a way to optimize it is to use invalidate(rect) for specific area that needs to be redrawn. At the same time, I could optimize the drawing even further if I knew which area needs to be redrawn inside onDraw().

In case of iPhone, I am using

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  method so I know the invalidated rectangle (which is passed as parameter).

Is there any way to get this rectangle in Android?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested:

It looks like canvas.getClipBounds() gets me the invalidated area within onDraw(), even though Android documentation is not clear about it at all. This rectangle can also be (0,0,0,0) so be careful when using it.

Comment: Thank you.  This is something that *really* needs more discussion (and documentation!!!).